# Pgadmin4 (Editing Table with characters)

Tags: pgadmin-4

So when I insert data in from the SQL Shell, it's fine.  However, when I try do it the same way using the GUI (view/edit data function), whenever I enter the city (character - size 50), only the 1st letter shows, but not the complete city name.  When I insert the data from SQL shell, it works perfectly.  But when I try to insert the data using the view/edit data function, only the first letter appears.  Does anyone know why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in pgAdmin4 and recently got fixed, Fix will be available in next public release of pgAdmin4.
Reference: [Link](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2830)